How can I disable command substitution when declaring a zsh alias to speed up shell startup?
My .zshrc contains, amongst others, the following alias declaration:
alias cleanbiber="rm -rf $(biber --cache)"

I use it to sometimes "reset" biber (the Perl tool used in tandem with biblatex) because it sometimes has (used to have?) issues that can only be resolved this way. biber --cache merely prints the path to its cache, but it does take a second or two, and I've noticed that this slightly slows down my zsh startup. I didn't know that aliases "expand" their command substitutions when saved. Is there an alternative way to declare this alias, so the saved alias is effectively rm -rf $(biber --cache) and not rm -rf [path]?
Thanks in advance!


I didn't know that aliases "expand" their command substitutions when saved.

The shell expands substitutions before it even knows you're defining an alias. The way it works is that various $-expansions are processed first, results split into words, wildcards expanded, and only then the 'alias' command is run.
A few special cases aside, almost every shell command is just a list of strings that all follow the same quoting rules – you see the exact same behavior between alias and echo and rm.
So the way you disable expansions during alias definition is the same way you'd do it for shell strings in general: either escape the $ using a backslash like \$(...) or put it in single quotes like 'rm -rf $(...)'.
(Though at some point if your aliases become unreadable due to excessive backslashes, it's better to define a function using name() { code; } as the block is not evaluated during definition.)
